# Sudo debug function vulneability

Tags: sudo, format-string

I am quite stuck with an assignment question, exploiting vulnerability (vfprintf) in sudo_debug function with ASLR ([CVE: 2012-0809](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/fulldisclosure/2012-01/att-0591/advisory_sudo.txt)). I can only use string format exploits.
ONLY ASLR IS ENABLED < NO FORTIFY_SOURCE
I must overwrite the value of `user_details.uid` variable. I have been examining stack to find patterns or offsets to crack it, but could not find any. I am quite unsure how to proceed. What to do next?

Answer (score 3):

You could start by reading the full description of [CVE: 2012-0809](http://archives.neohapsis.com/archives/fulldisclosure/2012-01/att-0591/advisory_sudo.txt) and then look for a [poc](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/25134/). A brief introduction to [format string exploitation](https://www.exploit-db.com/docs/28476.pdf) is a good starting point.